# Fixing Jira Kanban Board Task can't move or close issue

Tags: jira, jira-agile, kanban

I created a task on jira (agile) by using kanban board but, I couldn't move it to "in progress" column. Finally I found the solution. You can see the problem and the solution step by step via pictures.

The problem is this:
[image]

Follow the topic to find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the steps. if you know a better solution, please share it.

The solution is:

1. Go to administration panel, open integrity checker, ***select all*** and click to ***Check***.
2. Select ***Fix all*** and click ***Fix***.
3. You'll see the *fixed issues*. Then click ***OK***.
4. Finally you can do anything with your task again.

Now follow the pictures.

1. step 1
   [image: step1]
2. step 2
   [image: step 2]
3. step 3
   [image: step 3]
4. step 4
   [image: step 4]

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the usual reason for this problem is that the Conditions in the workflow are incorrect and the user does not match the rules set by them.

The problem answered by the main answer here only applies when you have corrupted data.

It also neglects the fact that you should treat corrupted data as a potential problem that you should investigate - it will be caused by crashes, or broken add-ons or scripts and you should track them down and fix them.

Comment: We had some server issues, it restarts sometimes. It may caused to this error.